# Adding a context menu to a DevExpress MVC Extension treeview

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, treeview, devexpress, contextmenu

I have been following [this example](http://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Example/Details/E4277) on how to get a context menu working with the tree view extension, and for now, I have just tried to implement the same functionality as is in the example to my application. When I run the application, the context menu does not work, but debugging the javascript shows an error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object 1 has no method 'GetHtmlElement'

When it jumps out of the init function to the ProcessNode function. Is there any known reason why this is happening? I have looked around the documentation and what not and to no avail.

If you need any more information from me, just leave a comment and I will provide what I can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer guys, thanks. It was a bit silly really, one of those human error moments. Took a long time to find though! The error was in the way I was recursively looping through all the child nodes of the parent node in the tree view.